# C socket programming - printing only one line

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

im trying to make C socket program which connects to telnet and I could send a command to it.

Comment: It seems the server you connect to sends some kind of information when you connect to it (have you tried to connect with actual `telnet` or similar program?). You need to read all that and parse it to find the prompt which tells that the server is ready to accept commands.

Comment: `&server_response` really should be `server_response`. `recv` doesn't NUL terminate the buffer, so you'll want zero it out first and pass your buffer length as `sizeof buffer - 1`, if you want to treat it as a string. Otherwise, check/use the return value to determine string length, and terminate appropriately.

Comment: Why do you think you should receive anything more than that?

Comment: I am not familiar with the OpenVPN Management Interface, but sometimes these kind of servers will not respond until they see a newline. You might try changing `"status"` to `"status\n"`

Comment: I thought if i send something like "status" it would send me back status of openvpn, because it is a command in management interface?

Comment: @RamEir How would it know you weren't sending "statuse" and just hadn't sent the "e" yet?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it,

Answer (score 3):

You don't send a line. A line is, by definition, terminated by a newline character.

You don't receive a line. There is no code to keep calling `recv` until a newline character is received.

So this code could only work by luck or by magic. It does not tell the other end where its message ends and does not attempt to read a message from the other side. It sends a few characters and then receives some random number of characters.

You have to actually implement some kind of protocol. You can't just send and receive random combinations and lengths of bytes over TCP and expect it to make any kind of sense.

If you're supposed to send a line, write code to send a *line*. And use that code to send.

If you're supposed to receive a line, write code to receive a *line*. And use that code to receive.

TCP has no idea what your "messages" are supposed to be. You have to code that.

Also, it's a minor nit, but this is wrong:

```
    recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

    printf("server response: %s\n", server_response);
```

You ignore the return value of `recv`. So how could `printf` possibly know how many bytes to print? You were given that information, but never kept it or passed it on!

Comment: But i have methods and it doesnt work. I will edit my post to show those methods, maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: @RamEir Where's the code to send a *line*? Where's the code to receive a *line*? If your protocol is sending and receiving lines, you need to write code that actually implements that protocol, that is, code that understands what a line is. Where is the code to send the line terminator? Where is the code to check the received data for the line terminator?